# Adding Sign In With Apple To An Existing Project

Tags: ios, auth0, apple-sign-in, apple-developer

I am attempting to add the SIWA feature in order to get approved for the AppStore. Up until now the process has been fairly repetitive (Twitter, Discord, Google), however, Apple is doing Apple and I am getting an error page when attempting to SIWA.

Things I’ve Tried:

Adding the Team and Key IDs
Adding SIWA to my current Identifiers in Apple Developer portal
Adding SIWA “Capabilities” in the XCode IDE for the project, thus Revoking and reinitializing the Provisioning Profile
Verified dev tenant
Hunches:

There are many tutorials that mention adding a “Service Id” for SIWA on the Apple Developer portal, however because I have already registered the apps reverse url for other Identities Apple gives me an error that the Identifier has already been used.

[image: Error message]

[image]

**5 Days Later**

Ok, so, instead of using the dev keys in accordance with Auth0, which is leaving the Application's Client Secret and Client ID fields empty, I entered them as though it were being used for production.

Now, there is an, "invalid client" error, after the login flow completes, which wasn't happening before. So, it seems the callbacks are going through, now it is about figuring out the invalid client error.

Comment: New development, your Service Id does not need to be the same as your app’s bundle ID. You can do something like, “com.myTeam.MyApp.service”, then tie that ID to the ID Group for your Entire app, for example, “group.myTeam.MyApp”. Once that is complete you may enter your callback URLs accordance with the above instructions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is related to app store policy and procedures, and is not a programming question as written

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to regarding edits (as there is no edit history for your question). That said: there's nothing here that can be answered on Stack Overflow, as this has nothing to do with programming (as written) - no code or any other details are provided, and your question seems to be around app id's. Also, for future questions - all detail belongs in your question, not in follow-up comments.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! My edit ability was delayed, when that was written. The screenshots are now in the question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon this is not about policies and procedures. It is looking to solve the error in the screenshot. I want to make it to the app after logging in with Apple...

Comment: Also, some times programmers have to configure applications, like when you assign values to vars in a .env file

Comment: I'm using the auth0 universal login and I didn't have to do any setting up on the client or in Apple regards to enabling the Apple ID. Only enabling it from the auth0 dashboard was sufficient. I'm also supporting other social logins via the universal login. List of all the supported social logins https://marketplace.auth0.com/features/social-connections

Comment: Also, you need to provide the client id and domain even for the dev environment of auth0.

Answer (score 0):

This, https://community.auth0.com/t/apple-login-error-invalid-client/56566/5?u=tristanb.newman

So, we were using an old private key. We needed to revoke the current one because it was lost, then make a new one with the same sub group as the Service ID, following the typical configuration steps outlined in Okta developer documentation, here, https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple